# Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{n}{(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Just like i know there is a formula that gives the following:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k i =\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$
I want to know if there's a formula for this sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{(i+1)}$$

I haven't been able to find it on the web.

Comment: Out of 3 equations not a single one has the right limits

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $n$ where you typed $i$?

Comment: Yes, I just fixed it. Sorry...

Comment: this $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n+1)} = 1$ is false. The true identity is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n+1)} = \infty$

Comment: After fixing the series sum is not right, it does not converge at all

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{i}{i+1}=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{i+1-1}{i+1}=\sum_{i=1}^k1-\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{i+1}=k-\sum_{i=2}^{k+1}\frac{1}{i}=k-(H_{k+1}-1)=k-H_{k+1}+1$$

Answer (score 2):

Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$, the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n+1}$$

cannot converge.

Note that

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{n}{n+1} &=\frac{n+1-1}{n+1} \\ 
 &=\frac{n+1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1} \\ 
 &=1-\frac{1}{n+1}.
\end{align*}$$

So

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{n}{n+1} &=k-\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n+1} \\ 
 &=k-H_{k+1}+1
\end{align*}

where $H_m$ is the mth [harmonic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html).

Comment: I think you meant to write the answer in terms of k, but I think understand. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I've fixed it.